# List Navbar Problems (Color, Functionality)

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, navigation

I have created a navbar using an unordered list. Here is my problem:

I cannot change the color of the text of the list items and for some reason I cannot click my links anymore (I was able to click them a while ago in development, no idea when they stopped working).

Here is what the items look like now:

http://gyazo.com/c089ed3f21368d4d2a1d91a52e129222.png

HTML:

```
<div class="grid_16 alpha" id="header">
    <ul id="nav" class="grid_4 prefix_1">
        <li id="nav_home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li id="nav_home"><a href="#">News</a></li>             
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#nav {
    color:white;
    margin-top: 54px;
}

#nav li {
    color: white;
    display: inline;        
}

#nav a:link {
    font-family: ColaborateThinRegular; 
    font-size: 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #353535;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    margin-right: 15px; 
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;   
}
```

Comment: can you attach jsFiddle?

Comment: Also dont set the id of two elements the same. Ids must be unique. Instead use a class.

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b2mCQ/). the problem with the coloring occured because you didn't specify `a:visited` as well as `a:link` so the color was purple.

The non-clickable problem.. has something to do with `href="#"` or some other code on your site that prevents it.. I've linked one of the buttons in jsFiddle to google and it keeps working after first click. Try it out

Answer (score 0):

After visiting the link your style stops working. Try implementing this:
`#nav a:visited {color: white;}`
Always remember ids are Unique.